# How to check if record is exists in c#

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm inserted in data into a database like below:

```
var N_ID = " 001T ";
var N_Email = N_EmailAdd;
TourCenterDBEntities NewsLetterEntities = new TourCenterDBEntities();
News_Letter NewsLetterDetails = new News_Letter();
NewsLetterDetails.N_id = N_ID;
NewsLetterDetails.N_Email = N_Email;
NewsLetterEntities.News_Letter.Add(NewsLetterDetails);
NewsLetterEntities.SaveChanges();
```

records save correctly to the database but before I insert I want to if that record is exists or not.how can I do that.

Comment: please include the method ` NewsLetterEntities.SaveChanges()` to the question

Comment: @un-lucky, I think this uses entity framework, in which case `SaveChanges()` is a .NET method. Also, it's not going to help find an answer to the question, it's unrelated.

Comment: @HoneyBadger : Am not familiar about EF, anyway thanks for the information

Answer (score 3):

before you insert, you can check like this:

```
if(NewsLetterEntities.Any(entity => entity.N_id == N_ID)) {
   // Return or throw, your choice
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this.it works for me.this is it

```
var existing = NewsLetterEntities.News_Letter.Where(l => l.N_Email == N_EmailAdd);
```